# Comment traduire la locution « (can) ill afford » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, adverbes, locutions

En anglais on a l'emploi *(can) [ill](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/ill) [afford](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/afford)*, avec l'idée d'« impact néfaste » sans négation dans la phrase : « If you can *ill afford* something, you should not do it or get it because it will cause problems » ([Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/ill)/anc. Merriam Learners). Par exemple, dans un film :

> [reporting on the failed invasion of Klendathu] 
> *Newsreel announcer* : Crisis for humankind. Fleet officials admit they
> underestimated the Arachnids' defensive capability.
> [switch over to the Federal council]
> *Newsreel announcer* : Accepting responsibility for Klendathu, Sky Marshal Dienes resigns. His successor, Sky Marshal Tehat Maru, outlines her new strategy.
> *Sky Marshal Tehat Meru* : To fight the bug, we must understand the bug. We can **ill afford** another Klendathu.
>
> [ Extrait de *Starship Troppers* (citation sur [imdb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120201/characters/nm0236225)) ]

Le dictionnaire donne aussi deux exemples :

> We can *ill afford* more bad publicity.
>  She bought a new car, which
> she could *ill afford*.

---

- Comment peut-on traduire cette locution et est-ce de la même manière dans les trois exemples ?

Comment: (Re)Voir la V.F. ou la V.O.S.T de Starship Troopers serait intéressant à cet égard.

Comment: C'est une locution verbale “can/could ill afford”. Le groupe “ill afford” n'est pas transposable à d'autres contextes. L'adverbe “ill” peut avoir ce sens dans d'autres contextes, mais il n'est plus guère utilisé en anglais moderne en dehors de cette locution.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Je comprends, je me fiais à la présentation dans Britannica...

Answer (score 1):

On peut en général traduire “*afford*” ou “*can afford*” par « (pouvoir) se permettre » ou « avoir les moyens ». Ces expressions peuvent se construire de plusieurs façons, principalement :

- se permettre de faire quelque chose ;
- avoir les moyens de faire quelque chose ;
- se permettre quelque chose [souvent, mais pas toujours, il s'agit d'argent pour acheter la chose] ;
- avoir les moyens de quelque chose [une action ou un évènement] ;
- avoir les moyens [souvent, mais pars toujours, il s'agit d'argent pour faire ou obtenir ce qui a été mentionné précédemment].

L'adverbe “*ill*” dans ce contexte signifie « presque pas ». En français, dans ce context, on dit souvent « difficilement » ou « ne … pas vraiment » ou « ne … guère » (ce dernier est soutenu).

> We can ill afford more bad publicity.
> Nous ***pouvons difficilement nous permettre*** plus de publicité négative.

> She bought a new car, which she could ill afford.
> Elle a acheté une nouvelle voiture qu'elle ***ne pouvait pas vraiment se permettre***.
> Elle a acheté une nouvelle voiture, mais elle ***n'en avait pas vraiment les moyens***.
> Elle a acheté une nouvelle voiture, mais elle ***n'avait pas vraiment les moyens***.

> We can ill afford another Klendathu.
> Nous ***pouvons difficilement nous permettre*** un deuxième Klendathu.
> Nous ***n'avons guère les moyens*** d'un deuxième Klendathu.

Answer (score 1):

Il y a probablement plusieurs façons de traduire cela.

L'une est l'utilisation d'expression verbales contenant  l'adverbe "*difficilement*".

> (Harrap)
> **I can ill afford the expense**        je peux **difficilement supporter** cette dépense

They could ill afford another child : *Ils pouvaient **difficilement se permettre** d'avoir un autre enfant.* (user LPH)

- They could ill afford another disobedience from their men. : *Ils pouvaient **difficilement tolérer** un autre refus  d'obéissance de la part de leurs hommes.*  (user LPH)

Une autre possibilité consiste à remplacer « difficilement » par « *ne guère* » dans les formes ci-dessus (Robert collins)

- je **ne** peux **guère supporter** cette dépense
- They could ill afford another child : *Ils **ne** pouvaient **guère se permettre** d'avoir un autre enfant.* (user LPH)
- They could ill afford another disobedience from their men. : *Ils **ne** pouvaient **guère tolérer** un autre refus  d'obéissance de la part de leurs hommes.*  (user LPH)

Une autre possibilité consiste à utiliser les expressions « *tout juste* » et  « *à peine* ».

- She bought a new car, which she could ill afford. *Elle a acheté une nouvelle voiture, une dépense qu'elle pouvait **à peine** faire.*

Answer (score 0):

Suite à une [suggestion en commentaires](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/51773/comment-traduire-la-locution-can-ill-afford#comment107343_51773), j'ai jeté un coup d'oeil à un sous-titre identifié Zone 2 de *Starship Troopers* et on y trouve :

*La flotte admet avoir sous-estimé les défenses des arachnides.*
*Assumant sa responsabilité, l'amiral Diènes démissionne.*
*Son successeur, l'amiral Meru, résume sa nouvelle stratégie.*
Pour affronter l'insecte, il faut comprendre l'insecte.
On ne peut **guère** se permettre un autre Klendathu.